# MySQL database backup and conflict

Tags: mysql

How do i properly export mysql database?
Example below is SUPER SIMPLIFIED version of what i experienced..
Now consider i have 3 tables, user, fruits, & user_basket

user

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | john |
| 1 | jacob |
| 2 | jim |

fruits

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | apple |
| 1 | orange |
| 2 | lemon |

user_basket

| id | user_id | fruits_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

SCENARIO:
from the example above, we know that jacob has 3 fruits.
i ran server>data export from mysql workbench, and this is the backup sequence..

1. user table backup finished
2. fruits table backup finished

**2.a. jacob created a new fruit. fruits-table(id: 3, name: grapes)

**2.b. jacob added this fruit to his basket. user-basket-table(id: 4, user_id: 1, fruits_id: 3)

3. user_basket table backup finished

As you may now noticed, the backup of fruits table doesn't contain the new row - fruit grapes (id: 3, name: grapes), however the link was recorded in step 3 (user_basket table).

In a scenario we USE this backup data. User jacob fetched/query his basket list, and fruit with id #3 does not exists, it would cause error/missing data.

What's the solution?

Possible followup question: Have u tried turning off your live server before doing a backup?

my answer: wouldn't it be the same if..

1. i turn off the sql server

1.a. person is still fiddling with stuff, and a millisecond multiple database table save happens and some did not.

2. server now off.

Comment: make database readonly then backup and then revrt

Comment: @eshirvana  that's usually not an option for a production database.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable the checkbox option "Create Dump in a Single Transaction" when you export. This ensures that the data included in the dump represents exactly one moment in time. Data changes in any table that were committed after the start of the whole export are not included.

See it in the screenshot at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html

[image]

Comment: where is this tick box located, can't seem to locate it

Comment: I added a screenshot with the checkbox highlighted with a red box.

Comment: very much appreciated. i realized i am using export to dump proj folder instead of export to self-contained file. all good!